# Spot the different

Tags: code-golf

## Introduction

This challenge was originally the ["Among Us"](https://github.com/ChocolateOverflow/Writeup-YASCON_CTF_2020/tree/master/Misc/Among_us) challenge in the "Misc" category of YASCON CTF 2020. (The link includes an answer to that challenge. Click at your own risk.)

You're given a lot of files, 1 of which is different from every other files. Your job is to find that 1 different file.

## Challenge

- Input: the file names of all the files to be searched through.
- Output: the name of the 1 different file.

It is guaranteed to have at least 3 files, exactly 1 of which is different file.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Least bytes wins.

## Example Input and Output

Input:

> 1.txt 2.jpg 3.png 4.mp3

Output:

(`3.png` is different)

> 3.png

Comment: By defining difference, does it only care about its content? Is meta info (permission, create time, last modify time, ect.) included?

Comment: Are the name of the files given? Or we're given a folder of files?

Comment: @tsh Only file contents are checked.

Comment: @SketchySketch The input is the file names.

Comment: *exactly 1 of which files are the exact same*? surely **all but 1** *of which files are the exact same*

Comment: Are the listed files guaranteed to be the only ones in the directory?

Comment: Please incorporate your clarifications into the challenge text

Comment: Hello, I am temporarily closing this challenge while a few things are being clarified.  In particular tsh's question should be answered and the sentence "It is guaranteed to have at least 3 files, exactly 1 of which files are the exact same, and 1 different file." needs some clarification.

Comment: It should be "exactly 1 of which is different". @xnor You are given the full path to the files as input. Files are opened locally.

Comment: @JohnZhau I don't think that answers my question. I want to know, say, in your example with input `1.txt 2.jpg 3.png 4.mp3`, might the directory with those files contain some other file `5.bmp` that wasn't listed? If so, do we ignore it that file? And, your comment that we are given the full path to the files as input doesn't match the written spec or example, so you should edit the challenge to match if you mean it.

Comment: @xnor The file names include the path to the file. For example, in a bash shell, running `spot_the_different a b c` will only work on the 3 given files, regardless of what other files are in the directory as they aren't given as input. Files not included in the input are untouched.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 71 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.find(u=>!x.filter(v=>(R=n=>[...read(n,'binary')]+'')(u)==R(v))[1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc6xDoIwFIXh3aeoU@@N2ARwbSefAN0IA8JtrEpL2kLg6TEGWY3bP3w5OY96rEPjTR@PoTct@c7ZJ82Llssk1SS0sS0MUu0/@YrkYZQKCmmlKoUQnuoWbMJvxtZ@5lgdOEcYUMoCRsQyrXBxQYQ5ROqAU3N37OI6YleaIlMsFXGKHHe/TPbLnI3W5MnGTed/LJ6@pvfGRtBQ8vVHwni2Rb7FiivE5Q0)

---

66 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.find(u=>!x.filter(v=>(R=n=>read(n,'binary')+'')(u)==R(v))[1])
```

works on my computer. But I cannot make it run on TIO. Maybe due to the version of SpiderMonkey.

Comment: SpiderMonkey documents say it use `readFile()` to read a file. But the interpreter actually expects `read()`. I don't know why. But it does save bytes...